# Conditional formatting

Tags: multidimensional-array, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-statements

Conditional formatting based off formulas and cells value.

My task is to highlight cells in a data set that do not have a formula. The first part is simple, as I used the (and) function and the (isformula) function. Please see my formula below.

```
=(AND(ISFORMULA($V72),ISFORMULA($W72)
```

Basically if the cell contained a formula we get a true response. All of the pieces of the (and) function must be true for the statement to be true. 
I added the IF statement, so my formula could be changed to have the end result of True when really False and False when really true.

Conditional formatting will highlight the cells in referenced row that  Basically if my (IsFormula) function was false I need it to become true to apply my formats. IF statement if true will have text as "False" and if the logical test is false the false response will be text as "True".

```
=IF(AND(ISFORMULA($V3),ISFORMULA($W3),ISFORMULA($X3)),"False","True")
```

Everything that I mentioned above works fine. I need to only apply the conditional formatting if the cells do not have formulas and the cell value is greater than zero. Please help me to figure this out.

I tried this

```
=AND(ISFORMULA($V5),ISFORMULA($W5),ISFORMULA($X5),($V5 >0),$W5>0)
```

and

```
IF(AND(ISFORMULA($V5),ISFORMULA($W5),ISFORMULA($X5),($V5 >0),$W5>0),"False","True")
```

Even though the cell has a value of zero it is still being formatted. 
Please help.

Comment: I got so confused with your explanation.  Do you mind to take a snapshot or give some data to show what went wrong?  Remember, a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Sometimes `AND` doesn't work in `Conditional Formatting`.  Try `(ISFORMULA($V5)*ISFORMULA($W5)*ISFORMULA($X5)*($V5 >0)*($W5>0))` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following formula, starting in V5 -or wherever your data block actually begins -then highlight the entire data range and typing within the conditional formatting box: =AND(ISFORMULA(V5) =FALSE,V5>0). This answer is based on whether I understood your explanation correctly.